# How to query different GET requests in PHP

Tags: php, sql

In my app I have different GET requests (getPull getPush etc), I am trying to figure out how to have the controller query through and return the correct "workout". I want the controller to return the proper get function from the model based on the request. How to do it?

WorkoutModel.php

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . "/Database.php");


class WorkoutModel
{
    public static function getPushWorkout() : array {
        $sql = "SELECT * from tblworkouts WHERE type=0";
        $results = array_push();
        return Database::executeSql($sql);
    }
    public static function getPullWorkout() : array {
        $sql = "SELECT * from tblworkouts WHERE type=1";
        $results = array_pull();
        return Database::executeSql($sql);
    }
    public static function getLegWorkout() : array {
        $sql = "SELECT * from tblworkouts WHERE type=2";
        return Database::executeSql($sql);
    }
}
```

WorkoutController.php

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . "/ControllerRequest.php");
require_once(__DIR__ . "/ControllerResponse.php");
require_once(__DIR__ . "/../model/WorkoutModel.php");
require_once(__DIR__ . "/../model/types/workout.php");

class WorkoutController
{

    static public function get(ControllerRequest $request) : ControllerResponse {
        $workout = $this->$request->WorkoutModel::getPushWorkout();
        $PullWorkout = WorkoutModel::getPullWorkout();
        $LegWorkout = WorkoutModel::getLegWorkout();
        return new ControllerResponse($workout);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you have no idea what you are doing and what you want to do, How will anyone have idea how to help you?

Comment: I know what I want to do. I want to the controller to return the proper get function from the model based on the request?

Comment: Based on *what* in the request?

Comment: @DonR in the controller im just not sure how to have it so when there's a GET request it will go through to check if its a getPushWorkout, getPullWorkout, or getLegWorkout and then return with the parameters for that function that are listed in the Model.

Comment: @ZankrutParmar what i want to do is have the controller check to see what workout to get (from the controller) by id or param or something but I don't know how.

Comment: It's becoming clear that you have no familiarity with how HTTP works, which is why you don't know how to ask your question. Start by Googling "query string"